# How to create table on web page that automatically populates multiple cells based upon the entry of one?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

My friend has a very advanced excel spreadsheet he uses for a financial modeling class. He's asked me to help him turn the spreadsheet into an web page. He's been rather adamant that it maintains a spreadsheet like design. Meaning when one cell of the table is filled in then one ore more cells of that table are filled in based upon some formula for that respective cell.

My initial thought was to find some Excel to HTML converter... to no avail. All the ones I found either didn't maintain the formula's or weren't free.

Has anyone come across this problem before? If so, what did you do?

If not, any suggestions how to code a table like this using HTML/Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: I would make it an embedded Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: I am not very familiar HTML but the `RangetoHTML function` by De Bruin might be a starting point (in this case used to insert excel in an HTML email body): http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm